# React component doesn't unmount

Tags: jquery, reactjs, razor

I have a simple react component inside a `cshtml` (Razor) page using the following syntax:

`<div id="reactContainer"></div>`

And I have a react index file which mounts a component inside that div using:

`ReactDOM.render(<MyContainer/>, document.getElementById('reactContainer'));`

The problem I am having is that as I navigate to and from the `cshtml` page which has this element on it, more components get mounted but the old ones never get unmounted, this is causing my grief as none of cleanup logic is called.

Note that navigation away from the Razor page is handled using jquery ajax calls and there is no full page refresh, I simply replace the html using `$(target).html(result);`.  Maybe that could be causing it not to unmount, what would be a viable solution?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why use `$(target).html(result)`? Can you try using `this.state` instead to add elements to the component?

Comment: Unfortunately all the navigation etc is done in separated complicated legacy jquery code.  Its a small react component on a big application, we are migrating it piece by piece

Comment: Can you show the code as to how you're fully implementing the component? I can't think of a situation where using `setState` is not possible.

Comment: @Andrew the component is empty, it's a simple `<div></div>` element.  Imagine there are several other buttons on the UI, all done via Jquery and razor, clicking on any of these button will cause an Ajax request which will result in a `$(target).html(result);`.  The component is a child in that *target*, the component is not responsible for the navigation

Comment: I'm having a hard time envisioning your approach. But I believe the heavy reliance on regular DOM manipulation within React is causing issues. My only suggestion would be to migrate more of your app at once.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, your suggestion is essentially what we have recommended to our team but given that's its a large app, only small bits and bobs are being done in React, hopefully someone else might have a workaround :), appreciate your time.